# Filtering folders from a list when using LINQ to sort to find the oldest file

Tags: c#, linq, fileinfo

I am currently using the code below to get the oldest file in a given path.  Recently a folder was created in that path that is quickly become the oldest "file".  How can I modify the linq to filter directories and only report on files?

```
var fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFileSystemInfos();
var oldestFile = fileInfo.OrderBy(fi => fi.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look only for files like below:

```
var oldestFile = fileInfo.Where(fi => fi is FileInfo)
                         .OrderBy(fi => fi.CreationTime)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

The method `GetFileSystemInfos` returns an array of `System.IO.FileSystemInfo` objects. This class is the base class of both `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` objects, please have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo?view=net-5.0). As it is mentioned in the previous link:

> A `FileSystemInfo` object can represent either a file or a directory,
> thus serving as the basis for `FileInfo` or `DirectoryInfo` objects

So by passing the predicate

```
fi => fi is FileInfo
```

to the `Where` method above you get only the objects that represent files.

Answer (score 0):

`GetFileSystemInfos` Will show you all of the files and directories. If you want just filter files you can use `GetFiles` instead of `GetFileSystemInfos`.

Example:

```
    var fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles();
    var oldestFile = fileInfo.OrderBy(fi => fi.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note:
`GetFiles` has better performance than `GetFileSystemInfos` because this will not load all of files and folders in memory.
So it's good practice to use  `GetFiles` instead of `GetFileSystemInfos` if you just want filter files.